# Showing the discrete measure is a measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathcal{F}}$
**Definition:** Let $\Omega$ be a countable set and $\scrF = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. Let $\mu:\scrF \rightarrow [0,\infty]$. To each $x \in \Omega$ we associate some $\mu(x) \geq 0$. Then for any $A \subseteq \Omega$ we define
$$
\mu(A) = \sum_{x \in A} \mu(x).
$$

I want to show that this satisfies a the definition of a measure on $(\Omega, \scrF)$. I think the fact that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ is evident but I just want to make sure I'm not making any stupid mistakes with monotonicity and countable additivity even though I know the question is basic.

> 1. If $A \subseteq B$ then it follows that $\sum_{x \in A} \mu(x) \leq \sum_{x \in B} \mu(x)$ since every $x \in A$ is also an element of $B$ and $\mu(x) \geq 0$ for every $x \in \Omega$.
> 2. Let $(E_n)$ be a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. By definition we have that
>    $$
>    \mu\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right) = \sum_{x \in \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n} \mu(x).
>    $$
>    Because these sets are disjoint, the sum can be split into the components of the union as
>    $$
>    \mu\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right) = \sum_{x \in E_1} \mu(x) + \dots + \sum_{x \in E_n} \mu(x) + \dots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n),
>    $$
>    and so we conclude that $\mu$ is a measure.

Does this make sense? In particular the argument for splitting the sum when proving countable additivity. Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Comment: Did you mean $\displaystyle\mu(A) = \sum_{x\in A}\mu(x)$?

Comment: Yes I did thanks! Fixed

Comment: In step 2 I think you need to do a bit of work.  What if the union of the $E_i$'s is an infinite set?  You should show that in the case that the measure of this infinite set is less than infinity then you can break apart the sum as you did.  Then you should argue this in the case that the measure is infinity.  And argue that the sum of the measures of the $E_i$'s is also infinity in this case. Lastly, I think you should state that sum on the right hand side of the last equation is the sum of the measures of the $E_i$'s.